# What does 'best wisdom' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, is-it-a-phrase

I recently came across the following excerpt:

> In other words, once an issue becomes political, people are no longer free to make their own choices based on their personal preference and their best wisdom.

What does `best wisdom` mean in this context?

Comment: "Best judgment" -- what their intuition or insight suggests to them is the best course of action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sense of the phrase "best wisdom" as used in the excerpt seems slightly out of tune with what I take to be the normal sense of the phrase—namely, "soundest judgment under the circumstances." The phrase as used here might be translated as "knowledge, understanding, and judgment uninfluenced by consideration of extraneous factors such as politics." But once an issue becomes enmeshed in politics, politics ceases to be an extraneous consideration—and assessing the issue in a way that ignores politics may not be wise. Applying one's "best wisdom" in a politicized situation undoubtedly becomes more complicated—because it entails taking more factors into account—but it doesn't cease to be one's "best wisdom" under the altered circumstances.

In my view, a more satisfactory way to put the argument would be to dispense with the term "best wisdom"—since I disagree with the author's implicit idea that it describes something incapable of adapting to take new and more complicated considerations into account—in favor of something like "uncomplicated standards of judgment." That would yield this restatement of the quotation:

> In other words, once an issue becomes political, people are no longer free to make their own choices about it based on personal preference and uncomplicated standards of judgment.

Answer (score 1):

Sound judgment or common sense could also fit here.